# Including images in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I would like this dropdown select to show an image with an alt text in front of the options, how can I do this?

```
<form>
    <select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank')">
        <option value="#">Select one</option>
        <option value="#"></option>
        <option value="http://www.url1.com">www.url1.com</option>
        <option value="http://www.url2.com">www.url2.com</option>
        <option value="www.url3.com">www.url3.com</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

That is not a button!, it a select dropdown.

You should use [ddSlick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) which is a free light weight jQuery plugin that allows you to create a custom drop down with images and description.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to show images in an html `<select>` - you would have to use a custom solution like this one: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Answer (score 0):

**DOM** model doesn't allow **img** elements inside **option** elements, so you cannot put image into a select. Please have  a look at [**an HTML language reference**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html). But you can use **JavaScript** or **jQuery** to put an image at the left or right of the menu whenever a new option is selected.

However, in Firefox you can just add **background image** to option:

```
<select>
    <option style="background-image:url(image1.png);">OPTION1</option>
    <option style="background-image:url(image2.png);">OPTION2</option>
    <option style="background-image:url(image3.png);">OPTION3</option>
</select>
```

And in other browsers the only way of doing that would be using some JS widget library, like for example [**jQuery UI Selectable**](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/).

olsn's link is also a good example.